# Can't release guides in illustrator CC (2015)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2015, guides

I'm trying to delete a guide and I can't seem to figure out how. I did a Google search and found that I have to select the guide, <kbd>right click</kbd> and select `release guide`. However, it doesn't show [image]

My guides are not locked either. And when I go to `View > Guides > Release Guides`, I can't do that either. [image]

Comment: Hi Camille, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Have you ever heard of screen captures that do not require a camera?

Comment: Of course...didn't see why it would matter since you can still see what's going on, and I made this post through my phone. Rude.

Comment: Its just that the moire is terrible on mobile devices. That is also rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AI creates guides as layers.  Simply go to your layers palette and delete them by dragging them to the trash can icon on the bottom right of the layers palette.

I always create a separate group specifically for my guides and I'll usually lock it just to be safe.

[image: layers]

Answer (score 3):

Your guide is probably in a layer or sub-layer that you have locked.

Open your `Layers` palette (`Window > Layers` or <kbd>f7</kbd>) and twirl open (click the triangle) all parts you have locked. There's bound to be some `<Guide>`s there, one of them your little cyan offender. Unlock it, select it with the `move` tool (or you could just 'meatball' it in the `Layers` palette) and hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It's the layer options. If you right click on the layer the guide is on, and click layer options, there should be a checkbox that says lock guides. Uncheck and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should just drag over the guides that you want to delete or release and press the Delete Key on the Keyboard. Make sure the guides are not locked.